# Parsing TimeSpan with optional minus sign

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783407%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The *styles* parameter affects the interpretation of strings parsed using custom format strings. It determines whether input is interpreted as a negative time interval only if a negative sign is present (TimeSpanStyles.None), or whether it is always interpreted as a negative time interval (TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative). If TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative is not used, format must include a literal negative sign symbol (such as "-") to successfully parse a negative time interval.

I have try the following:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("-0700", @"\-hhmm", null, TimeSpanStyles.None)
```

However it returns 07:00:00. And fails for "0700".

If I try:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("-0700", "hhmm", null, TimeSpanStyles.None)
```

It fails too.

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("0700", new string [] { "hhmm", @"\-hhmm" }, null, TimeSpanStyles.None)
```

Does not fail for both "0700" and "-0700", but always return the positive 07:00:00.

How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: As a workaround, if you can't get this to work, you could parse a `Duration` in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). Will see what I can do with `TimeSpan` though...

Comment: Thanks for hint. But it is a simple script I do not want to and an additional library, I would rather use a StartsWith('-') instead.

Comment: Fair enough. I've included it in my answer anyway, but mostly for the sake of other readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *looks* like this isn't supported. From the [custom TimeSpan format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) page:

> Custom `TimeSpan` format specifiers also do not include a sign symbol that enables you to differentiate between negative and positive time intervals. To include a sign symbol, you have to construct a format string by using conditional logic. The Other Characters section includes an example.

This does seem really odd though. Ick.

As mentioned in my comment, you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) project's [`Duration` parsing](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/duration-patterns.html) for this; overkill for just this case, but if you had other date/time work in the project, it could be useful.

For example:

```
var pattern = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("-hhmm");
var timeSpan = pattern.Parse("-0700").Value.ToTimeSpan();
```

Comment: So, the `styles` parameter is useless. One could just append `-` sign in front?

Comment: @TN.: Somewhat useless, yes. The whole feature seems a little underdesigned, to be honest... (I mean, the style has an effect, but not a terribly useful one - at least for custom patterns. Maybe it's better for standard patterns...)

Comment: @TN.: Assuming you meant `0700`, yes. It requires that the hour value isn't more than 23 though. `7000` is harder to handle. (If you actually want to handle that, let me know, but I suspect you meant 0700 :)

Answer (score 2):

It does look like you annoyingly need to check yourself if it begins with a leading `-`

```
// tsPos = 07:00:00
string pos = "0700";
TimeSpan tsPos = TimeSpan.ParseExact(pos, new string [] { "hhmm", @"\-hhmm" }, null,
    pos[0] == '-' ? TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative : TimeSpanStyles.None);

// tsNeg = -07:00:00            
string neg = "-0700";
TimeSpan tsNeg = TimeSpan.ParseExact(neg, new string [] { "hhmm", @"\-hhmm" }, null,
    neg[0] == '-' ? TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative : TimeSpanStyles.None);
```